# Agregar filas de un data frame a otro,, donde no me coincide le número de columnas pero los nombres de algunas de estas

Tags: r, union

R.Studio:
Buenas tardes, tengo 2 data frame, uno de ellos tiene 7 columnas y el otro 3, quiero pegar la información del dataframe 2 (3 col) en el dataframe 1 (7 col), y que pegue la información que de las columnas que coincidan entre ambas bases.

Nota: los dataframes no tienen mismo numero de columnas pero si mismos nombres de las columnas que coinciden.

Intente hacerlo con un fulljoin pero me crea como nuevas columnas,  las columnas que me coinciden del data frame 2 al 1, duplicandose, tipo_ variable.x y variable.y

este es el codigo que realice:

B_Universo <- full_join(Base_1,base_2,by="ID")

Estoy trabajando en R studio.

Agradezco mucho su atencion y colaboracion referente a este tema y el codigo si me lo pueden facilitar, Gracias!!

Comment: Bienvenida a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour]. Considero que tu pregunta está bien planteada, pero le está haciendo falta el código que has escrito durante el intento que describes. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta para añadirlo. Dale una leída a [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: Edité las etiquetas, añadí R y quité RStudio pues, según la descripción de la etiqueta, la pregunta parece no tener nada que ver. Si me he equivocado, eres libre de [edit] y ponerla de nuevo. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola Johana, bienvenida, tu pregunta se parece mucho a "tengo este ejercicio, resuélvanlo", este tipo de preguntas, no suelen ser bien recibidas, te sugiero que la edites, y muestres que has intentado, para saber que formas parte de la resolución de tu problema, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: Hola Johanna, el funcionamiento de todos los `join` de `dplyr` es exactamente el que mencionas, por diseño esta establecido que no se van a eliminar columnas, si tenes una `Col1`  en los dos dataframes, al hacer `join`  tendrás una `Col1.x`  (del df de la derecha) y `Col1.y` (del df de la izquierda).  Si ese ese el problema hay formas sencillas de resolverlo.